# How to create ShareDB realtime database with quill editor in React Native application?

Tags: react-native, real-time

I am trying to create a quill editor in react native application where users can collaborate and edit like google docs.

Can we use ShareDB in mobile application? I saw a point in ShareDB github "**Ideal for use in browsers or on the server**". And, another point

**First, get a ShareDB.Connection object by connecting to the ShareDB server instance:**.

The question is how can I access ShareDB instance from client i.e mobile apps?

ShareDB : https://github.com/share/sharedb

Answer (score 0):

Try using WebView to access the collaborative page on server.